# How can i define method in file with extension .class?

Tags: java

I need to define another method in ITuple.class like

```
public Object getValue(int i);
```

but with Float

```
public Object getValue(float j);
```

How can i add it ?

I'm new to storm so Can I find the method that make the same job as I searched and couldn't find , isn't right?

Comment: .class are compilated files. You cannot edit them. You have to edit the .java file and then compile it into a .class file.

Comment: I confirm all the comments and answers for this question but If you want to send a float inside your method like variable "a" do like this getValue(((int)a)) and it will give you  something :).

Comment: Thanks , i misunderstanding with the job of the method cause i got error in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286302/java-lang-float-cannot-be-cast-to-entities-tweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what `getValue(int)` does.  Here is the description from the javadocs:

> Object getValue(int i)
>
> Gets the field at position i in the tuple. Returns object since tuples are dynamically typed.

As you can see, the `int` argument is the *position* in the tuple; i.e. the index.  Tuple position are *inherently* integers, so adding an alternative that takes a floating point argument doesn't make any sense.

---

Supposing (hypothetically) that it did make sense to add a `getValue(float)` overload, then the way to do it would be to:

1. download the source code (".java" files),
2. modify the interface in the `ITuple.java` source file
3. modify the source files for classes that implement the interface
4. build them all to produce new JAR files
5. use those JAR files in your application

... and repeat this patching procedure *every time* you upgraded your Apache Storm release. That is probably a bad idea, even if what you were doing made sense.

But attempting to modify ".class" files directly is an even worse idea.

Comment: ohh , yes i got it but i'm facing problem with  java.lang.Float cannot be cast to entities.Tweet . i'll post another one . Thanks for replying

Comment: I see.  The actual problem you were trying to solve was a type cast failure.  This is completely not the way to solve it.  (As in, there is zero chance it would have helped.)  I would advise you to take the time to take the time to do a Java Tutorial.  You appear to be struggling with the basics of the Java language ... like what a typecast does and does not do, and how to diagnose the problem of a typecast failure.

Comment: And looking at the linked question in more detail, it looks like you may have made a mistake in the code that created the `TridentTuple` instances in the args list.  Your code is written to expect the first element of the tuple to be a `Tweet` but is is actually a `Float`.  You CANNOT solve that mismatch with a typecast.  What you have to do is to figure out why the tuples contain something unexpected (to you!) and so something about that.

Comment: Thanks for your replying . I have some bascis in Java not bad . I'm just take a quick decision for detecting this error . Thanks any way. I detect the real problem and tried to solve it . If I will not able, I will post it here .

Comment: can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381499/indexoutofboundsexception-index-1-size-1 ?

Answer (score 0):

.class files are compilated java files. I assume you found this file in a library.

I'm afraid to inform that this code isn't yours and you cannot edit it.

What you can do, however, is extends the `ITuple` interface in a `MyITuple` interface and add whatever you want in it.